# Choosing components of a wifi customer tracking system

Tags: wireless, management, logging

We are installing customer WiFi for our retail locations and want to run analytics on customer usage.

Information we would like to know:

1. How often a customer visits a location?
2. What locations a customer visits?
3. How long a user is in a location?
4. How much data a user consumes/uploads while on our network?

I have experience in programming and database systems, but not with high level network engineering. So with raw usage data (i.e. csv, tab, mer files), I could get all this data within our program, although I'm imagine some routers come with reports built in or third party software that integrates and reports... I'm trying to get educated on as many aspects as I can so we can role out this network successfully.

What specifications should I look for in a router so I can obtain usage information from it to run analytics on?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The really first step is to look for [Radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) support. With Radius support you are able to manage the authentication authorization and accounting (aaa).

In this case you are not concerned with authentication and authorization since you are, essentially, asking for accounting. Accounting is the process by which a network device (called NAS - Network Access Server in the Radius world) periodically sends accounting messages to the RADIUS server (the aaa server) about the activity of its clients (the supplicants). For example an accounting message could transport information about how many bytes are beeing transmitted by the client during a session and so on.

The really general idea is to have this schema:

```
     Client         ->       AP          ->       Radius 
(Radius supplicant)    (Radius Client)       (Radius Server)
```

If you want to achieve a more granular specification you could even think using [NetFlow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflow) but this represents a more complex scenario.

If you need suggestions about products please use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations).